# QGIS: expression in attribute table between greater than and less than with different categories in one field

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, qgis-expression

I am trying to create a field that shows the following different categories in the same field:

Variable = verschil bouwhoogte

```
"Verschil bouwhoogte" <3
"Verschil bouwhoogte" => 3 and  "Verschil bouwhoogte" < 6  
"Verschil bouwhoogte" >=6 and "Verschil bouwhoogte" <9
"Verschil bouwhoogte" >9
```

So far i can only get it to work using a new field for each expression

Comment: Difficult to understand what you are trying to select with your expression. Can you explain with words which values you are trying to select? And a screenshot showing the attribute table

Comment: While the question about what you want to do with your expression is unclear, the expression needs to be corrected. At least, it should be written like this `"Verschil bouwhoogte" >= 3 and  "Verschil bouwhoogte" < 6` and `"Verschil bouwhoogte" >= 9`. The equal sign comes after the greater than sign.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [the Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator), you can use the following expression:

```sql
CASE 
    WHEN  "value" < 3 THEN 'cat_01' 
    WHEN  "value" >= 3 AND "value" < 6 THEN 'cat_02'
    WHEN  "value" >= 6 AND "value" < 9 THEN 'cat_03' 
    WHEN  "value" >= 9 THEN 'cat_04'
    ELSE 'cat_00'
END
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

*I deleted my very short answer, as it was clearly not the answer OP needed.
My answer consisted mostly of an image, with the idea that OP could find more information in the online manual of QGIS, in the language of his choice.
But I understand now that this is not the way of StackExchange.
I strive to do better next time.*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should provide a little bit more text to your answer. The bot just reads your text and can't find an answer. Describe what you do as provided in the image.